# PureMVC and Flex for Beginner's

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, puremvc

I am core java and Java EE developer with loads of experience in UI and web applications. I have encountered in a project now which has Flex and ActionScript as technologies for development and i have totally no idea about what is the above two and never worked in technical environment.

I just wanted a start as how it works, what the things to be taken care of to start with PureMVC and Flex coding.

Examples are Java has class files as output, we need to code in .java and literals expressions methods and classes. What's dere in flex and AS?

Is PureMVC same as MVC used in web applications?

Comment: More info about Flex go here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flex.html and for more info about PureMVC go here: http://puremvc.org .  PureMVC is ported to a number of different technologies, and can be used to create HTML based applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PureMVC is an MVC framework with a flex port (actually, the original was developed in flex and later ported to other platforms).  It was one of the first frameworks (along with Cairngorm) to be released for flex.  I find it to be a little restrictive myself with a learning curve.

You'll find AS3 to be somewhat natural for a Java developer.  The syntax may be a little funky, but you will have most of what you want directly translated to AS3.  AS3 source files end in *.as and the output is either a *.swf (executable) or a *.swc (library).

If you pick up flex, you'll also find *.mxml files which is its markup language.  The fundamental difference between MXML and programming in Android's XML template or webdevelopment with HTML is that the MXML file actually compiles to a pure actionscript class.

For a Java developer, I would recommend that you take a look at [spring actionscript](http://www.springactionscript.org/).  It one of the first (if not the first) dependency injection frameworks and comes out of the port directly from Java Spring.  You will get your annotation-based injection or injection through XML configuration.

Personally, if I were to start from scratch as a beginner, my framework of choice is [swiz](http://swizframework.org/) for its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I not really recommend you start with PureMVC and Flex. Most of all enterprise solution use [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) + Flex. Parsley very similar to Spring and you as Java and Java EE developer will be more easy understand how it work.

Comment: Ok but i need to get onto Flex

Comment: Parsley supports both flex and pure actionscript